# What is the over-volt, over-current or over-power limit on a pin to an Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: voltage-protection

I have an input voltage going to an Arduino pin that could be up to 5.25 V. I have many options on solving the problem but the simplest would be to include an inline resistor that limits the power that the over-voltage can deliver to the board.

I have done some experiments with the board using a pin that is set to `INPUT`, `INPUT_PULLUP`, `OUTPUT` set to low and `OUTPUT` set to high. I sent a voltage through a 33 kOhm resistor to the pin in those configurations, and swept 0-6V across the resistor. The pin voltage when in `OUTPUT` mode was very rigid, holding its output perfectly against the resistor.

When in either `INPUT` mode, the overvoltages seemed to happily pass through the resistor, driving at most 65 uA and 0.15 mW into the pin while it was raised to the 5.5 V value. it seems to me then that the Arduino pins are quite resilient to overvoltage, but this might be an incorrect assessment.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Atmel (i.e. Microchip) Datasheet for the ATMega2560?  All of these limits and more are covered there.  Keep in mind that just because a condition doesn't cause an immediate failure, doesn't mean it doesn't cause damage.  Some damage is cumulative and only shows up over time.

Comment: If you use that pin for input only, you can just add a voltage divider using two resistors (one to the input line and another to ground).

Comment: All inputs have **clamping diodes**. Combined with your resistor they will prevent the voltage from going too high.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum voltage on any IO pin is VCC+0.5V or 5.5V when powered from 5V.

The maximum "injected" current is not specified in the datasheet, but typically 1mA is a reasonable value to assume.

So 5.25V at 65uA is, while not ideal, at least tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

The ATMega2560 Datasheet is here:

[Microchip ATMeta2560 Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561-Datasheet-DS40002211A.pdf)

The important section for questions like this is: **ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS**

For this chip we are provided:

[image: Absolute Maximum Ratings ATMega2560]

Note the Voltage on any Pin... specification that I have highlighted.  This says that under NO circumstances should you allow a pin to go below -0.5V or above (Vcc + 0.5V) or you risk damaging the chip.  So if you are running at 5.0V that means you can safely apply a voltage of +5.5V to the pin.

Your 0-6V signal is over the limit for this device and you will fall into the other section that I highlighted, the "NOTICE".

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to go near the Absolute Maximum Ratings, let alone drive a pin at exactly the maximum rating, as only a slight difference will put you over the top. Absolute Maximum Ratings are not design guidelines, which is why the datasheet explicitly states: "Exposure to absolute maximum rating conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability." 5.25V would be acceptable, though not a sign of a good design, but 5.5V is a no-no (all this assuming a supply voltage of 5V).

Comment: Yes, that's quite correct.  It's also important to keep in mind the actual Vcc.  If it's a bit low but still within limits, then an otherwise acceptable input voltage could cause damage.